# can only post to post method in asp.net core webapi

Tags: asp.net, json, http-post, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created non-core webapi projects to interact with mobile apps. for example If I created a controller called Data and it has a method called Search like show below. the project has been configured to send and receive json data.

```
[HttpPost]
public Searchresult search(SearchQuery s)
{
   // code to search
    return sr; //object of type Searchresult
}
```

I could send post request to this method using postman by using the following url
     http://localhost/api/Data/search

Similarly I can create other functions inside the controller and call them using the route '/api/[controller]/[action]'.

I could not do the same in asp.netcore web api project. The routing was controller level i.e '/api/[controller]' and every time I posted only the post method was hit. implemented int eh following way. It gets executed when I post to 'http://localhost/api/Data'

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post([FromBody] testclass t)
{
    return "{\"a\":\"" + t.a + "\",\"b\":\"" + t.b + "\"}";
}
```

The following code is never executed when I post to "http://localhost/api/Data/test"

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string test([FromBody] testclass t)
    {
        return "{\"a\":\""+t.a+"\",\"b\":\""+t.b+"\"}";
    }
```

Comment: This not a "normal" behavior of a Core Api, so there's most likely something wrong with your routes or some other issue not covered by the provided code. You'll have better luck by sticking to a specific scenario you're having issues with (rather than an abstract explanation of what you think the problem is), and posting your *actual* code, since often, by creating dummy sample code, you'll often eliminate or otherwise obscure the issue you're facing in your real code.

Comment: actually this is my actual code. I created a dummy project to test core web api so that I can start implementing the actual project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely because your controller doesn't understand difference between your routes. You need to define the routes explicitly like this:

```
[HttpPost("post")]
public string Post([FromBody] testclass t)
{
    return "{\"a\":\"" + t.a + "\",\"b\":\"" + t.b + "\"}";
}

[HttpPost("test")]
public string Test([FromBody] testclass t)
{
    return "{\"a\":\""+t.a+"\",\"b\":\""+t.b+"\"}";
}
```

And then post to them.

Comment: Forgotten had posted this. Well the above solution did work.